# Style guidelines (e.g. PEP8) for long error messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

I am raising some exceptions in my Python code, and to give an as clear as possible diagnose, the error message is quite detailed. Is there some PEP8-like guideline on how to print this error message? Should I add newlines in the exception such that it prints more nicely?

Comment: What is the indented audience of that message? Users should never see the exception and developers care more about the content than the format.

Comment: @KlausD. It's software that runs numerical simulations, wrapping commercial 'black box' software. Most users are probably familiar with Python, but not necessarily want to see the source, they just want to run a simulation. However, if they make a mistake in the 'black box' software, our software can't continue hence the error is raised. I noticed that novel users typically have no idea what went wrong and they either have to contact the developers or start working through the source code. That's why I wanted it to be more detailed, because there the users get to see the message.

Comment: The exception is indented to be shown to developers who can interpret it. It is not there to confuse novel users. So, do not expect any official guideline to exist that clarifies how to present user friendly exceptions.